# Is there a way to put a value from span element to html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

pardon me as I am a new coder.

I have a span element that displays the value of a slider

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
output1.innerHTML = slider1.value; // Display the default slider value
        
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider1.oninput = function() {
output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
</div>
<h4>Score: <span id="demo1"></span></h4>
```

I want to send this value (from "demo1") to a form input element as a prefill. I have some idea that prefill can be done with `<input value="">`

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you want to send the *value* of score in `<input type"text">`? Or Do you want to control the slider using `<input type="text">`?

Comment: @Shrey I simply want to send the value to '<input type = "text">' if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you set the `innerHTML` to `output1`, you can set value of `input` by using `.value` property.

```js
let slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
let output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
let input = document.getElementById("txtInput");

output1.innerText = slider1.value; 
input.value = slider1.value;

slider1.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const sliderValue = this.value;
  output1.innerText = sliderValue;
  input.value = sliderValue;
});
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
</div>
<h4>Score: <span id="demo1"></span></h4>

<input type="text" id="txtInput">
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only pass the default slider value which is 5. 

I want the value of <input type"text"> as I change the value of score using the slider. The js code send the default value of the slider which is 5 in the <input type="text" id="txtInput">